# Getting "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception trying to override toString()

Tags: java, jgrapht, jgraphx

I'm trying to write an algorithm which builds and visualizes a Gomory-Hu-Tree out of a given network, using JGraphT and JGraphX. I read in another post that I had to override the toString() method of the used DefaultWeightedEdge class to visualize the tree. However, I'm getting the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge cannot be cast to testtest.testeins$MyEdge
    at testtest.testeins.buildGraph(testeins.java:129)
    at testtest.testeins.createAndShowGui(testeins.java:94)
    at testtest.testeins.access$0(testeins.java:90)
    at testtest.testeins$1.run(testeins.java:44)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The class where I use the overriding

```
public static class MyEdge extends DefaultWeightedEdge {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(getWeight());
        }
    }
```

this way of overriding was given in the post I mentioned.

Other code where I use the new class

```
 public static ListenableGraph<String, MyEdge> buildGraph() {

        Graph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> gg = new SimpleWeightedGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

        DefaultListenableGraph<String, MyEdge> g = new DefaultListenableGraph(gg);

        String x1 = "x1";
        String x2 = "x2";
        String x3 = "x3";

        g.addVertex(x1);
        g.addVertex(x2);
        g.addVertex(x3);

        MyEdge e = g.addEdge(x1, x2);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 1);
        e = g.addEdge(x2, x3);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 2);

        e = g.addEdge(x3, x1);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 3);

        return g;
    }

private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DemoGraph");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ListenableGraph<String, MyEdge> g = buildGraph();
        JGraphXAdapter<String, MyEdge> graphAdapter = 
                new JGraphXAdapter<String, MyEdge>(g);

        mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);
        layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());

        frame.add(new mxGraphComponent(graphAdapter));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Graph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> bsp = createbspgraph();

        GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> tree = new GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree(bsp);

        System.out.println("fdg");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        }); 

    }
```

Comment: `Graph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>` should most likely be `Graph<String, MyEdge>` since that is the type of your edge.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings, and address them properly.  I think you’ll find that the compiler gives you a “raw type” warning for `GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> tree = new GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree(bsp);`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you @Progman.

Comment: However I now have problems with a imported method returning `DefaultWeightedEdge` whereas I need my overridden type `MyEdge`. Using the `tree.getGomoryHuTree()` method of `GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree<String, MyEdge> tree = new GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree<>(g);` returns me a `SimpleWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>`. How can I change that returned graph to be based on `MyEdge` insted of `DefaultWeightedEdge`?

Comment: @Infty Why should the `getGomoryHuTree()` method return a graph where your `MyEdge` edge is used? As far as I see it you get a different graph with weighted edges, so that's what the `DefaultWeightedEdge` is used for. No need to be it a specific custom object.

Comment: @Progman Because when I try to visualize the tree with my `createAndShowGui()` method using a `ListenableGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>`, the resulting image doesn't show the edge weights, it only shows the start-/end vertex like f.e. `(v3: v1)`, but I need to know the edge weights of the tree for my algorithm. In the post I mentioned, where I got the idea from, it was said that overriding the `toString()` method from `DefaultListenableEdge` fixes this problem. Therefore I need a way to convert the `<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>` graph I get from GomoryHu to be a `<String, MyEdge>` graph.